# SAS log copy/paste includes line break

Tags: sas

While working inside SAS, I'll often highlight a dataset or variable name as it appears in the Log, copy it, and then paste it into the enhanced editor. The selection is from the middle of  a single line of the log (no line breaks in the source). Unfortunately, pasting seems to always include a line break along with the seven or eight characters that I actually want. Is there a setting for me to change to avoid getting this extra line break?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I just backspace automatically when it's relevant.

Comment: I'm going to guess that SAS is using HTML or RTF formatting and that, when you copy/paste, the editor is stripping out that formatting and leaving you with some extra space. Sometimes pasting into a very simple editor, like Notepad (on Windows), will help, but it's probably just an annoying artifact you must live with.